# Python/Django avisar de que tu session va a caducar

Tags: python, django

Tengo una cookie que tiene definido:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 3600
```

Y me gustaría avisar al usuario cuando vaya a caducarse.

¿Cual es la mejor manera?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes extraer la fecha de caducidad de la sesión desde el template con:

```
{{ request.session.get_expiry_date }}
```

Solo necesitas un poco de js para mostrar el aviso al usuario cuando se acerque la fecha.

Sino siempre puedes usar AJAX y crear una vista donde se pueda consultar con js. En la vista harías algo similar:

```
caducidad = request.session.get_expiry_date()
```